# Stacking Raster in R: Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)

Tags: r, loops, raster, landsat

I have several hundred Landsat8 scenes with 12 bands each. **I have stored them all in one folder.** And now i try to stack them all together in R for easier batch processing of indices. 
This is the code im using:

```
#Create List of files (whole path is used) 
L8files = list.files(path = 
"C:/Users/Felix/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/Daten/R_Test/Only_TIF",
                 full.names=TRUE)


#Write Names of Files in List
getprefix = function(string){
substr(string, 61, 113) 
} 

L8list = lapply(L8files, getprefix)


#Defining function to stack
stack_raster= function(file){
  setwd("C:/Users/Felix/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/Daten/R_Test/Only_TIF")
  prefix = substr(file, 1, 106)
  suffix = "tif"

  inband1 = raster(paste (prefix, paste("B1", suffix, sep ="."), sep=""))#coastal aerosol
  inband2 = raster(paste (prefix, paste("B2", suffix, sep ="."), sep="")) #blue
  inband3 = raster(paste (prefix, paste("B3", suffix, sep ="."), sep="")) #green
  inband4 = raster(paste (prefix, paste("B4", suffix, sep ="."), sep="")) #red
  inband5 = raster(paste (prefix, paste("B5", suffix, sep ="."), sep="")) #NIR
  inband6 = raster(paste (prefix, paste("B6", suffix, sep ="."), sep="")) #swir1
  inband7 = raster(paste (prefix, paste("B7", suffix, sep ="."), sep="")) #swir2
  inband8 = raster(paste (prefix, paste("B8", suffix, sep ="."), sep="")) #PAN
  inband9 = raster(paste (prefix, paste("B9", suffix, sep ="."), sep="")) #cirrus
  inband10 = raster(paste (prefix, paste("B10", suffix, sep ="."), sep="")) #TIRS1 
  inband11 = raster(paste (prefix, paste("B11", suffix, sep ="."), sep="")) #TIRS2
  inbandQBA = raster(paste (prefix, paste("QBA", suffix, sep ="."), sep=""))#Pre-Collection Quality Assessment

#stack bands
 inimage = stack(inband1, inband2, inband3, inband4, inband5, inband6, 
 inband7, inband8,inband9, inband10, inband11, inbandQBA)

setwd("C:/Users/Felix/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/Daten/R_Test/stacked")
sat = substr(file, 67, 70)
date = substr(file, 84, 91)
writeRaster(inimage, filename = paste(date, sat, sep="_"),
          format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
}
#Loop 
for (i in L8list){
  stack_raster(i)
}
```

I think the stack function doesn´t know which file to use, but i also dont know how to change that.
Below you see what Debug shows me. I cant really read anything out of it but that the file doesnt exist.

```
function (x, band = 1, objecttype = "RasterLayer", native = FALSE, 
  silent = TRUE, offset = NULL, ncdf = FALSE, ...) 
{
  x <- trim(x)
  if (x == "" | x == ".") {
    stop("provide a valid filename")
  }
  start <- tolower(substr(x, 1, 3))
  if (!start %in% c("htt", "ftp")) {
    y <- NULL
    try(y <- normalizePath(x, mustWork = TRUE), silent = TRUE)
    if (!is.null(y)) {
      x <- y
    }
  }
  fileext <- toupper(extension(x))
  if (fileext %in% c(".GRD", ".GRI")) {
    grifile <- .setFileExtensionValues(x, "raster")
    grdfile <- .setFileExtensionHeader(x, "raster")
    if (file.exists(grdfile) & file.exists(grifile)) {
      return(.rasterFromRasterFile(grdfile, band = band, 
        objecttype, ...))
    }
  }
  if (!file.exists(x)) {
    if (extension(x) == "") {
      grifile <- .setFileExtensionValues(x, "raster")
      grdfile <- .setFileExtensionHeader(x, "raster")
      if (file.exists(grdfile) & file.exists(grifile)) {
        return(.rasterFromRasterFile(grdfile, band = band, 
          objecttype, ...))
      }
      else {
      }
    }
  }
  if ((fileext %in% c(".HE5", ".NC", ".NCF", ".NC4", ".CDF", 
    ".NCDF", ".NETCDF")) | (isTRUE(ncdf))) {
    return(.rasterObjectFromCDF(x, type = objecttype, band = band, 
      ...))
  }
  if (fileext == ".GRD") {
    if (.isNetCDF(x)) {
      return(.rasterObjectFromCDF(x, type = objecttype, 
        band = band, ...))
    }
  }
  if (fileext == ".BIG" | fileext == ".BRD") {
    return(.rasterFromRasterFile(x, band = band, objecttype, 
      driver = "big.matrix", ...))
  }
  if (!is.null(offset)) {
    return(.rasterFromASCIIFile(x, offset, ...))
  }
  if (fileext %in% c(".BIN")) {
    r <- .rasterFromNSIDCFile(x)
    if (!is.null(r)) 
      return(r)
  }
  if (!native) {
    if (!.requireRgdal(FALSE)) {
      native <- TRUE
    }
  }
  if (native) {
    if (fileext == ".ASC") {
      return(.rasterFromASCIIFile(x, ...))
    }
    if (fileext %in% c(".BIL", ".BIP", ".BSQ")) {
      return(.rasterFromGenericFile(x, type = objecttype, 
        ...))
    }
    if (fileext %in% c(".RST", ".RDC")) {
      return(.rasterFromIDRISIFile(x, ...))
    }
    if (fileext %in% c(".DOC", ".IMG")) {
      return(.rasterFromIDRISIFile(x, old = TRUE, ...))
    }
    if (fileext %in% c(".SGRD", ".SDAT")) {
      return(.rasterFromSAGAFile(x, ...))
    }
  }
   if (fileext == ".DOC") {
   if (file.exists(extension(x, ".img"))) {
      return(.rasterFromIDRISIFile(x, old = TRUE, ...))
    }
  }
  if (fileext %in% c(".SGRD", ".SDAT")) {
    r <- .rasterFromSAGAFile(x, ...)
    if (r@file@toptobottom | r@data@gain != 1) {
      return(r)
    }
  }
  if (!.requireRgdal(FALSE)) {
    stop("Cannot create RasterLayer object from this file; perhaps you need 
to install rgdal first")
  }
  test <- try(r <- .rasterFromGDAL(x, band = band, objecttype, 
    ...), silent = silent)
  if (class(test) == "try-error") {
   if (!file.exists(x)) {
      stop("Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not 
exist)")
    }
    stop("Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.")
  }
  else {
    return(r)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier trick that should work when each landsat image (with their bands) is in a separate folder. Then the following can be applied:

```
list <- list.files(path='C:/ENTERPATHHERE', full.names=TRUE)
inimage <- stack(list)
```

The above code works for me. If you apply it and it still doesn't for you you might want to check whether all the locations of your rasters are written correctly.

Hopefully I was able to help!

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation that the code is correct. Though I still cant figure out why it wont work for me. I still get the same error.                                                
The code for reading and saving the raster works well outside the loop, but not within the loop.

Comment: Another problem that might be the case is that you define the function stack, but also use the function from gdal from it, which overwrites the gdal function. You might want to give your function a different name

Comment: I changed the name of the function, so there cant be any confusion with using the same name, but still i get the same error.

Comment: The problem lies in the loop, so you might want to check the class of the "i" in the for loop and see if it is the same as when you test it without the loop. If it is not the same you might want to change. Other than that I don't know if I will be able to find the issue without having the source data.

Comment: Thanks for still caring, after two days desperately trying to find the issue i moved on and wrote some other code which works.